# Combine two mouseevents in jQuery

Tags: jquery

i've got a problem with chaining two mouseevents.
I want the page only to check if an element is hovered when the mouse button is hold down.
this is my code:

```
$("main").on("mousedown", ".wordButton", function() {
            mouseDown = true;
            $(this).addClass("selectedButton");
            $("main").on("mouseenter", ".wordButton", function(){
                if(mouseDown){
                    $(this).toggleClass("selectedButton"); 
                }
            });
        });
 $("main").on("mouseup", function(){
            mouseDown = false;
            $(".selectedButton").removeClass("selectedButton");
 });
```

This works fine as long as the mousebutton isnt clicked. When the button was clicked once, the page is always checking for hovering. it's like the mousedown event always fires.
What am i missing here?

Comment: dont do spurious coding..why are you doing this.do not nest event ..take event out of.also what is `main`

Comment: What is `main`? `$('main')` :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"mouseenter" event handler will cause duplicate handler when mousedown event fired once more.
if you want check that element is hovering, use `jQuery(elem).is(":hover");`

```
$("main").on("mousedown", ".wordButton", function() {
    mouseDown = true;
    $(this).addClass("selectedButton");
    if( mouseDown && $(this).is(":hover") ){
        $(this).toggleClass("selectedButton");
    }
});
$("main").on("mouseup", function(){
    mouseDown = false;
    $(".selectedButton").removeClass("selectedButton");
});
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/is/

Sorry for my poor English, I hope that my answer was helpful.
Thank you!